# Vue: how to fire an event on a sibling component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

In Vuejs, I have a parent component (P), and two child components (C1 and C2).  The parent has objects which it shares with both child components.

Component C1 displays the objects (in a table) and component C2 lets the user modify the properties of the shared objects.  Because the objects are shared as objects, I am updating their properties directly in C2, and the changes are displayed in C1.

The problem is that C1 is responsible for saving changes (by making an ajax call to the server).  If the user modifies a property directly in C1, it triggers the change event, and an event handler makes the call.  However if the property is updated in C2, the change event is not fired in C1, so the change is not persisted.

So, the question is, how do I fire a change event in C1, based on an event in C2?  I have an event bus in place (in the root element).  I could (perhaps) use an event listener to grab the element (e.g. with jQuery), and fire the event, but obviously this is not the most elegant way to do it.  What's the Vue way?

Comment: you should use vuex for this scenario. you requirement demands single source of truth. only vuex will store/persist the changes no matter which component triggered it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly: You're sharing an object between two children and you're manipulating that object in either child component directly?

That pattern itself is the problem. You don't want to manipulate state inside a child component. The clean way that'll keep the reactiveness is to bind the object via a prop from the parent to both child components. The children should never manipulate the state of the prop object (vue should actually throw a warning if you do that), they should only emit an event that they want to change the object by using:

```
this.$emit('input', newObject)
```

Now simply listen to that event in the parent and manipulate the object there, or, for simplicity you can also use the v-model pattern as described [here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/add-v-model-support/).

```
<c1 @input="myUpdateFunction" />
```

or with the v-model pattern

```
<c1 v-model="mySharedObject" />
```

That's it. If your other component has the same object bound to it as a prop as well, it'll update its template automatically.

If you want an even more elegant way to share state for an entire application I suggest using [Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex).

Comment: Hi Philip,  At the bottom of this section, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow, it says that changes in child affect the parent when the prop is an object.  Are you sure that it is not a good idea?  (By the way, I trialed Vuex but found the overhead was really significant.)

Comment: Yes I'm sure, that's also why it's packed with a warning sign in the documentation. You should always use the v-model approach for this. With that approach you'll use Vues reactivity model properly without any side-effects. The child that implements the v-model pattern should only manipulate a copy of the state and communicate that change via event to the parent. That'll allow the value to be passed to the other child component in a clean way while preserving reactivity. If manipulate a prop directly, vue will show a warning in the console as well (at least when using webpack dev server).

Comment: @KimPrince here's an example I assembled quickly of how to update the state of both components using v-model: https://codesandbox.io/embed/oxy5o8985z

Comment: Thanks Philip, that's sensational.

Answer (score 2):

Your question it is not too clear.However you can use `eventBus` and it will work fine.

> My recommendation though,is to use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html).

You can manipulate the store properties and whenever the properties changing,the changes will be reactive and applied to all components.

So if you have two components c1 and c2,and in store you have a property `name: 'John Doe'`.

If in c1 component you change the name like: `this.$store.state.name = 'Jane Doe'` this change has also take effect to component c2.

Of course it is not so simple.In vuex store you should have [state](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html),[getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html),[mutation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html),[actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html) and on your components to use computed properties to use fetch the store properties though getters.